# Modal not closing when clicking on Backdrop (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, react-props

I'm having problems when trying to close a modal by clicking in the Backdrop.

Below I have a functional component where there is a form with some inputs that, when filled in and the save button is clicked, a modal appears. I'm using **show** constant to manipulate it, such as the methods **showModal** and **hideModal**. The SaveButton component does not interfere with anything related to this problem, that is why I'm not showing it here.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import SaveButton from '../../UI/Buttons/SaveButton/SaveButton';
import Modal from '../../UI/Modal/Modal';


const CreateProject = () => {
    const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

const showModal = () => {
    console.log(show);
    setShow({ show: !show });
};

const hideModal = () => {
    console.log(show);
    setShow({ show: false });
};

const onSubmit = (data, e) => {
    showModal();
    e.target.reset();
};

const fields = [
    {
        name: "Project Name",
        type: "text"
    },
    {
        name: "Lens Quantity",
        type: "number"
    },
    {
        name: "Description",
        type: "textarea"
    }
];

return (
    <div>
        <form id="parent"
            style={{ width: "100%", display: "flex", top: "20%", justifyContent: "center" }}
            onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <div>
                <div>
                    {
                        fields.map(({ name, type }) => (
                            <div key={name}>
                                <div className="input-group col" style={{ marginTop: "3px" }}>
                                    <div className="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span className="input-group-text">{name}</span>
                                    </div>
                                    {type !== "textarea" ?
                                        <input type={type} min="0"
                                            onKeyDown={e => (e.keyCode === 189) && e.preventDefault()}
                                            className="form-control" name={name} ref={register({ required: true })} />
                                        :
                                        <textarea className="form-control" name={name} ref={register} />
                                    }
                                </div>
                                {errors[name] && <span style={{ color: "#cf1b1b", display: "flex", paddingLeft: "18px" }}>Please enter a {name}.</span>}
                            </div>
                        ))
                    }
                </div>
                <SaveButton />
            </div>
        </form>    
         <Modal show={show} modalClosed={hideModal}>
                Success!
        </Modal>
    </div>
  )
}

export default CreateProject;
```

The modal appears, but I can't close it, such as the Backdrop. Both should disappear when clicking in the Backdrop.

**Backdrop** component

```
import React from 'react';
import './Backdrop.css';

const Backdrop = (props) => (
    props.show ? <div className="backdrop" onClick={props.clicked}></div> : null
);

export default Backdrop;
```

I put some **console.logs** to see if the **show** constant value changes to false when clicking in the Backdrop and it does, but I don't know why the modal and the Backdrop don't disappear as they should when the **show** constant is set to false.

**Modal** component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Backdrop from '../Backdrop/Backdrop';
import Aux from '../../hoc/Auxiliary/Auxiliary';
import './Modal.css';

class Modal extends Component {
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        return nextProps.show !== this.props.show || nextProps.children !== this.props.children;
    }
    render() {
        console.log("Show", this.props.show)
        return (
            <Aux>
                <Backdrop show={this.props.show} clicked={this.props.modalClosed} />
                <div className="save-modal"
                    style={{
                        transform: this.props.show ? 'translateY(0)' : 'translateY(-100vh)',
                        opacity: this.props.show ? '1' : '0',
                    }}>
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            </Aux>
        );
    }
};

export default Modal;
```

**Auxiliary** component

```
const Auxiliary = (props) => props.children;

export default Auxiliary;
```

To make it easier to understand, here I leave the code example.

[image: Edit open-close-modal]

Thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the hideModal method, just call setShow method with a boolean value. Not with an object:

```
const hideModal = () => {
    console.log(show);
    setShow(false);
};
```

Comment: It was such a lack of attention! Thank you buddy!

Answer (score 1):

In `hideModal`  when you are calling `setShow({show: false})` you should be using `setShow(false)`!

I'm guessing you instinctively used it as though it was `setState`.

Comment: I really used as I thought it was setState! Lack of attention on my part